# Print .ascii declaration using Lodsb or just mov

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I'm writing this bootloader that just prints out some stuff on the screen. This is what I have so far in assembly:

```
    .globl _start

    .code16

_start:

    movw $0x0003, %ax
    int $0x10

    movb $0x0e, %ah
    movb $0x69, %al
    int $0x10

    movw $_header, %bx
    movb %bl, %al
    int $0x10

_header: .ascii "W\0"

    .org 0x1FE

    .byte 0x55
    .byte 0xAA
```

So right now it prints ASCII 69 ("i"), but I want it to print the `.ascii` declaration as well.  Right now I only have it set to `"W"` so I could find it easily in `Objdump`. I can't seem to get access to that value (57). I can `leal $_header, %edx` and such, but then I can't seem to access the value at `%edx`.

I tried using `lodsb`, but I can't seem to figure it out. I set `%di` to 0x00, and set `%si` to the address of `_header` with `leal %si, _header` but then my `lodsb` followed by `int 0x10` doesn't seem to print anything. Any ideas I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
movw $_header, %bx
movb %bl, %al
```

First, `movb %bl, %al` isn't reading a byte from memory into `al`, it's reading a byte from `bl`. You want to change it to:

```
movb (%bx), %al
```

To get just one character out of `_header` you could load that character from the memory into `al` directly:

```
movb _header, %al
```

Secondly, and most importantly, it appears that you're making several assumptions:

1. that your code starts running with `cs`=0x7c0, `ip`=0. It can be `cs`=0, `ip`=0x7c00 instead, but your code is expecting `ip`=0 (I infer from the code that the assembler starts assembling it with the implicit `.org 0`). You should make your code resilient to this second option. You can reload `cs` and `ip` to more suitable values with a jump instruction, something like this: `jmp $0x7c0,$_next` and the corresponding label on the next line: `_next:`.
2. that your code starts running with `ds`=0x7c0. `ds` isn't guaranteed to be set to any value you may want or need. You have to initialize it yourself.

Finally, what happens after the last `int $0x10`?

With the corrections your code should look something like this:

```
    .globl _start

    .code16

_start:
    /* .org 0 is implied here! But the code may start with ip != 0. */

    jmp $0x7c0,$_next
_next:
    /* We have just ensured that cs=0x7c0,ip=$_next */

    /* Let's now load data segment registers with proper values */
    movw %cs, %ax
    movw %ax, %ds
    movw %ax, %es

    movw $0x0003, %ax
    int $0x10

    movb $0x0e, %ah
    movb $0x69, %al
    int $0x10

    movw $_header, %bx
    movb (%bx), %al /* read into al a byte from memory at address from bx */
    int $0x10

    /* Halt execution, don't just execute whatever garbage is in memory */
    /*after the end of the code. */
_halt:
    hlt
    jmp _halt

_header: .ascii "W\0"

    .org 0x1FE

    .byte 0x55
    .byte 0xAA
```

Comment: The only two other things I can recommend now is setting `bh` to 0 ([see here](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm)) and looking at the disasssembly (try `ndisasm`: `ndisasm -b 16 BootSectorFile`) to see if the addresses/offsets are correct after all manipulations with `objdump` and whatnot.